# How many move controllers do you need to play Playstation Sports Champions?

Tags: playstation-move

Just bought the whole Eye/Move rig for Socom.  I'd like to get this Sports Champions game (I guess the PS3 version if Wii Sports).
When you are playing with multiple people can you pass the move controller around on their turn, or do you HAVE to have a separate controller for each person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No game requires 2 Move controllers but some of them are more fun if you have them.

Multi player games ( split screen kind ) require 2 or more controllers if you are playing the game at the same time as the second player ( like table tennis or volleyball ).

If it is a turn based game ( like Golf ) then you can pass the same controller around and it works.

Games like archery and gladiator are more fun if you have 2 controller even for the single player.